# How to check whether cpanel user is exist using cpanel API2

Tags: api, cpanel

I want to check whether the cpanel user is exist or not using the cpanel API2. I went through the documentation but couldn't find a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cPanel API 2 currently does not provide this function. But in the WHM API 1 have [listaccts](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/WHM+API+1+Functions+-+listaccts) function which allows you to search for a cPanel username to see if it exists.

API call would as follows.

```
/json-api/listaccts?api.version=1&search=username&searchtype=user
```

Answer (score 0):

cPanel API 2 currently does not provide this function. but you can use `get_file_information` function as a workaround to check if public_html exists